# Manually scoring logistic regression model in SPSS?

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, predictive-models

First off, I'd like to apologize for my cluelessness, but I've come across a problem that I honestly have no clue how to circumvent. My programming skills are extremely limited, and my company uses SPSS 19 for most of their data analysis needs. I built a rather complex (as in, lots and lots of predictors) binary logistic regression model based on a sample from our primary dataset and would like to apply it to the rest of the dataset, which is featuring the exact same variables. Here is where SPSS makes life difficult for me - a xml-model export function and scoring wizard exist, but SPSS won't actually let me load the model I've exported (and informs me that my model is either not valid, which seems dubious, or is not supported by SPSS Statistics, with no explanation as to why). I suppose my question boils down to this: 
Is there any, really just about any foolproof way to score the rest of the dataset with the testing model? I'd be willing to delve into R, which I have no experience with, to make it work, at this point I'm just very desperate indeed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've voted to close, since this is just a tech-support type question for SPSS. I would suggest trying the NABBLE group for this question (see the [SPSS links](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/807/1036)). Jon's answer though is the best you are going to get unless you provide a reproducible example though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the scoring wizard?  (I don't recall whether it is present in V19, but I know it is available at least in V20 but not in V18).  If you want to send me the xml file you generated and a small sample of the data, I can take a look (peck AT us.ibm.com).  Note that there is also an extension command, STATS PMML DISPLAY available from the SPSS Community website (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral) if you have the Python Essentials installed that will display the most important items from the PMML file and can help you see whether it is what you expect.

If you have done any data transformations to the data that are used in the model and need to be redone for the scoring data, see the TMS commands for capturing them in the PMML.

Still another option would be to try NOMREG (Multinomial Logistic), which also can save and score with PMML.